# How to add images to PSTCollectionView

Tags: ios5, pstcollectionview

Creating an grid view image gallery for iOS 4 and 5.  Not sure how to go about it. Please walk me through it.

Comment: Hope the solution may help others. All you have to do is, download the [PSTCollectionView](https://github.com/steipete/PSTCollectionView) and add PS to UICollectionView which will show as PSUICollectionView. And this will work on ios4.0 and greater.